# Powershell sending JSON variable to Python

Tags: python, powershell

I'm having a problem with sending a JSON variable from PowerShell to python.

That's the code I have for python:

```
import subprocess
import os 
import json

firstname = 'FirstName'
lastname = 'LastName'

args2 = '-FIRSTNAME %s -LASTNAME %s' % (firstname, lastname)

test = subprocess.run([
    'powershell.exe',
    'Path\\Test2.ps1',
    args2,
])

jsonvalue = json.loads(test)

print(jsonvalue)
```

And here's for PowerShell:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$FIRSTNAME,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$LASTNAME
)

$result = [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = $FIRSTNAME
    LastName = $LASTNAME
    FullName = $FIRSTNAME + " " + $LASTNAME
}

return $result | ConvertTo-Json
```

JSON output:

```
{
    "FirstName":  "FirstName",
    "LastName":  "LastName",
    "FullName":  "FirstName LastName"
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not CompletedProcess
```

From what I've read it looks like **subprocess.run** is returning **CompletedProcess** variable type. Unfortunately, although I tried to bypass it wouldn't work.

I think it might be pretty simple, but I cannot find an answer on my own.
I'm pretty new to Python and connecting those two languages might be a bit of overkill for a beginner but isn't that the best way to learn? :D

Comment: Shouldn't `-FIRSTNAME`, `firstname`, etc all be separate elements of `run`'s list argument, rather than combined in a single string value?

Comment: `arg2 = ['-FIRSTNAME', firstname, '-LASTNAME', lastname]; run(['powershell.exe', 'PATH...', *args2])`?

Comment: I tried to do it that way at the beginning, but it wouldn't work.

EDIT: Oh, I see, there's an asterisk before "args", now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` doesn't return a string containing the output; you want the `stdout` attribute of the return value.

```
test = subprocess.run(...)
jsonvalue = json.loads(test.stdout)
```

Or, use the `check_output` function instead.

```
test = subprocess.check_output(...)
jsonvalue = json.loads(test)
```